# Developing my own modem

Tags: serial-port, modem

I would like to develop my own modem for a custom communication network that will be detectable on the serial port by PC automatically. What I'm uncertain about is the protocol part of the AT commands and how to make it work seamlessly so that computer will detect the modem automatically.

I plan to use ftdi UART to USB converter to interface my microcontroller with the PC using standard serial interface. The PC will then use AT commands to communicate with the microcontroller that will in turn connect to another microcontroller over radio tranceiver and establish a two way serial connection over radio. The idea is that the PC on the other end will run PPPD and listen on it's own modem connection for incoming call and then bridge the connection with it's other internet interface that is connected to internet. The first computer will get it's own IP address using PPPD and will be connected to internet over this custom microcontroller based modem.

**But how do I implement the communication protocol between my controller and PC? What commands do I absolutely need to implement? How do I make sure that the computer recognises my controller which is connected over ftdi usb to serial adapter as a functional modem?**

Where can I find a speciffication of the minimum command set that is required of a modem?

In practice linux usually discovers a 3G modem automatically for example. Does that have to do with the actual USB identifier of the modem? Is it possible to have linux automatically discover an ordinary serial port modem? I'm thinking that the modem will be sending an AT idle ping repeatedly when it's plugged in so that linux should be able to detect it.

Comment: You have a big project, that's pretty good.. . but too many questions within on post . I think, start somewhere get coding, come back with more specific issues. But nice ideas

Comment: Questions `how do I implement the communication protocol between my controller and PC?` and also 'commands... need to implement` will be fleshed out as you get more progress going. start with a simple ping command

Comment: I think my main concern is probably best expressed like this: "how do i make the PC autodetect the serial modem? And which AT commands do I absolutely have to implement for a working modem?" I have a uart transfer working over the link BUT now I want to add AT commands to make it into a modem that can be autodetected by any PC. That's where I'm stuck right now.

Comment: Please describe what you mean by *"autodetected by any PC"*.  What do you expect to happen that currently does not happen?  Normally the device connected to a UART can notify the host of its presence by the DSR signal (but is rarely used).  Then it's up to the PC to guess or assume at what's connected to the UART.  If your USB device emulated something other than a RS232 UART device, then your options could open up.

Comment: So how does the PC then detect that it is a modem? What does the modem need to send in order for the pc to detect it as a modem? Unfortunately I do not have a real serial modem, but when one connects a 3g modem, it appears a serial port on the pc and also the network manager automatically detects it as a modem connection. But that's as I said usb so options are better. But is this kind of autodetection even possible with a usb to serial converter connected to a microcontroller? What does the microcontroller need to send into the serial port to tell the computer that it implements a modem?